# Why am I getting an infinite loop when calling two Intent services, one after the other?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-intentservice

I'll go straight to the point.

I need to consume some Google web services (`DistanceMatrix and Geocoding APIs`), before I can continue with the next step is necessary getting both responses. I've just met `IntentServices` and I read that this is possibly a good way to perform one task and then the other because they can comunicate using `Intents` and `BroadcastReceivers`. This way the second IntentService will know when the first one has done it's job.

**The following steps sum up what I want to achieve.**

1. Get response from `DistanceMatrix API`
2. Once this task is done, starting the other Intent service and
   passing in the response so that I can get an address from within the
   second intent service  and  geocode this one using `Geocoding API`.

However before I make this implementation was testing the code sending some messages to the console just to make sure both intent services can communicate to each other, but I'm getting an infinite loop.

```
I/MapFragment: DistanceMatrixService finished...
I/MapFragment: Running GeocodingService...
I/MapFragment: GeocodingService finished...
I/MapFragment: The whole process has finished...
I/MapFragment: DistanceMatrixService finished...
I/MapFragment: Running GeocodingService...
I/MapFragment: GeocodingService finished...
I/MapFragment: The whole process has finished...
I/MapFragment: DistanceMatrixService finished...
I/MapFragment: Running GeocodingService...
I/MapFragment: GeocodingService finished...
I/MapFragment: The whole process has finished...
I/MapFragment: DistanceMatrixService finished...
I/MapFragment: Running GeocodingService...
I/MapFragment: GeocodingService finished...
I/MapFragment: The whole process has finished...
```

The first IntentService is getting called when clicking a button

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DistanceMatrixService.class);          
    getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
}
```

The DistanceMatrixService class just sends a message back to main fragment.

```
public class DistanceMatrixService extends IntentService {

    public static final String ACTION_FINISHED = "ACTION_FINISHED";

    public DistanceMatrixService() {
        super("DistanceMatrixService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Run the heavy task just here
        //...

        // Once the job is done send a broadcast message to communicate that it has finished
        Intent bcIntent = new Intent();
        bcIntent.setAction(ACTION_FINISHED);
        sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
    }
}
```

When the first IntentService has finished the GeocodingServices gets started

```
private class DistanceMatrixBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(DistanceMatrixService.ACTION_FINISHED)){
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "DistanceMatrixService finished...");
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Running GeocodingService...");                    

                Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), GeocodingService.class);
                getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
            }
    }

}
```

Like the first IntentService this one just send a message to the main fragment

```
 public class GeocodingService extends IntentService{

    public static final String ACTION_FINISHED = "ACTION_FINISHED";

    public GeocodingService() {
        super("GeocodingService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // Run the heavy task just here
        //...

        // Once the job is done send a broadcast message to communicate that it has finished
        Intent bcIntent = new Intent();
        bcIntent.setAction(ACTION_FINISHED);
        sendBroadcast(bcIntent);
    }

}
```

And the `GeocodingBroadcastReceiver` class catches the message

```
private class GeocodingBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(GeocodingService.ACTION_FINISHED)){
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GeocodingService finished...");
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Running The process has finished...");
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, this is code to register both BroadcastReceivers which are called in the `onCreate()` method

```
    private void registerGeocodingReceiver(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(GeocodingService.ACTION_FINISHED);
    GeocodingBroadcastReceiver receiver = new GeocodingBroadcastReceiver();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

private void startDistanceMatrixReceiver(){
    Intent msgIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), DistanceMatrixService.class);
    msgIntent.putExtra("iteraciones", 10);
    getActivity().startService(msgIntent);
}
```

Comment: You're using the same action for both broadcasts and both Receivers - `"ACTION_FINISHED"`.

Comment: I think you need to make your `ACTION_FINISHED` strings unique. You are registering both `BroadcastReceiver`s with the same filter essentially.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem, I just changed the value of ACTION_FINISHED for both classes. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that both services have a constant declaration with the same value

```
GeocodingService.ACTION_FINISHED = "ACTION_FINISHED";
DistanceMatrixService.ACTION_FINISHED = "ACTION_FINISHED";
```

Just assigned a different value to each one.

```
GeocodingService.ACTION_FINISHED = "GEOCODING_FINISHED";
DistanceMatrixService.ACTION_FINISHED = "DISTANCE_MATRIX_FINISHED";
```

**Thanks again to the users who gave the right answer!**